# AngularJS localhost redirect to IP Address

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-code, npm-start

I started a tutorial regarding AnguarJS for beginners. I have setup my workstation already and ready to test a simple Hello World. Unfortunately, I cannot display this simple message in my localhost. Instead, it display the default IIS image and I've noticed also that my url is the current IP Address. Can anyone pinpoint what I missed here?

Please see below image for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The dev server shows that it is running on port 4200:

[image: server message showing "open your browser on http://localhost:4200"]

As the message says, you need to navigate to `http://localhost:4200` (instead of `http://localhost`, which it looks like is being served by IIS)

Comment: yes I also did that also. But, the output still the same

Comment: That's really weird. Does it work if you use `iisreset /stop` to stop the IIS service? Is `10.205.82.151` your computer's IP address or some other server?

Comment: I also did the iisreset but still, the same output. The said ip address is my current ip address when i throw ipconfig in cmd

Comment: Run `netstat -ao` to see which process has bound to port 80 and port 4200. You'll need to match netstat's 'PID' (Process ID) column against the 'PID'  column in the Task Manager 'Details' tab. Maybe something else is running another IIS service?